# Optimising php memory usage? wp-filebase plugin related

Tags: php, wordpress, memory

I'm using the [WP-Filebase](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/) plugin for Wordpress, and experiencing some fairly knarly results when the script needs more memory. Particular the script at ./wp-filebase/classes/Sync.php

Here's the script in question. Apologise for it's length, there is a pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/HiJPThqe).

My question is - is this coded really badly, as it uses an awful amount of memory. Giving a memory limit of 512 still hangs when it tries to sync a file of 500MB..

How can this script be improved to use less memory, generally?

```
static function DEcho($str) {
echo $str;
@ob_flush();
@flush();   
}

static function UpdateItemsPath() {
wpfb_loadclass('File','Category');
$cats = WPFB_Category::GetCats();
$files = WPFB_File::GetFiles2();    
foreach(array_keys($cats) as $i) $cats[$i]->Lock(true);
foreach(array_keys($files) as $i) $files[$i]->GetLocalPath(true);
foreach(array_keys($cats) as $i) {
    $cats[$i]->Lock(false);
    $cats[$i]->DBSave();
}
}

static function SyncCats()
{
$updated_cats = array();

// sync file count
$cats = WPFB_Category::GetCats();
foreach(array_keys($cats) as $i)
{
    $cat = $cats[$i];
    $child_files = $cat->GetChildFiles(false);
    $num_files = (int)count($child_files);
    $num_files_total = (int)count($cat->GetChildFiles(true));
    if($num_files != $cat->cat_num_files || $num_files_total != $cat->cat_num_files_total)
    {
        $cat->cat_num_files = $num_files;
        $cat->cat_num_files_total = $num_files_total;
        $cat->DBSave();         
        $updated_cats[] = $cat;
    }

    // update category names
    if($child_files) {
        foreach($child_files as $file) {
            if($file->file_category_name != $cat->GetTitle()) {
                $file->file_category_name = $cat->GetTitle();
                if(!$file->locked)
                    $file->DBSave();
            }
        }
    }

    @chmod ($cat->GetLocalPath(), octdec(WPFB_PERM_DIR));
}

return $updated_cats;
```

}

static function Sync($hash_sync=false, $output=false)
{
    @ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
    @set_time_limit(0);

```
wpfb_loadclass("Admin", "GetID3");
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

$result = array('missing_files' => array(), 'missing_folders' => array(), 'changed' => array(), 'not_added' => array(), 'error' => array(), 'updated_categories' => array());

$sync_id3 = !WPFB_Core::GetOpt('disable_id3');

// some syncing/updating
self::UpdateItemsPath();
WPFB_Admin::SyncCustomFields();

$files = WPFB_File::GetFiles2();
$cats = WPFB_Category::GetCats();

if($output) self::DEcho('<p>'. __('Checking for file changes...',WPFB).' ');
$db_files = array();
foreach($files as $id => /* & PHP 4 compability */ $file)
{
    $file_path = str_replace('//','/',str_replace('\\', '/', $file->GetLocalPath(true)));
    $db_files[] = $file_path;
    if($file->GetThumbPath())
        $db_files[] = str_replace('//','/',str_replace('\\', '/', $file->GetThumbPath()));

    if($file->file_category > 0 && is_null($file->GetParent()))
        $result['warnings'][] = sprintf(__('Category (ID %d) of file %s does not exist!', WPFB), $file->file_category, $file->GetLocalPathRel()); 

    // TODO: check for file changes remotly
    if($file->IsRemote())
        continue;

    if(!@is_file($file_path) || !@is_readable($file_path))
    {
        $result['missing_files'][$id] = $file;
        continue;
    }

    if($hash_sync) $file_hash = @md5_file($file_path);
    $file_size = (int)@filesize($file_path);
    $file_mtime = filemtime($file_path);
    $file_analyzetime = !$sync_id3 ? $file_mtime : WPFB_GetID3::GetFileAnalyzeTime($file);
    if(is_null($file_analyzetime)) $file_analyzetime = 0;

    if( ($hash_sync && $file->file_hash != $file_hash)
        || $file->file_size != $file_size || $file->file_mtime != $file_mtime
        || $file_analyzetime < $file_mtime)
    {
        $file->file_size = $file_size;
        $file->file_mtime = $file_mtime;
        $file->file_hash = $hash_sync ? $file_hash : @md5_file($file_path);

        if($sync_id3)
            WPFB_GetID3::UpdateCachedFileInfo($file);

        $res = $file->DBSave();

        if(!empty($res['error']))
            $result['error'][$id] = $file;
        else
            $result['changed'][$id] = $file;
    }
}
if($output) self::DEcho('done!</p>');

foreach($cats as $id => $cat) {
    $cat_path = $cat->GetLocalPath(true);
    if(!@is_dir($cat_path) || !@is_readable($cat_path))
    {
        $result['missing_folders'][$id] = $cat;
        continue;
    }       
}

if($output) self::DEcho('<p>'. __('Searching for new files...',WPFB).' ');

// search for not added files
$upload_dir = str_replace('//','/',str_replace('\\', '/', WPFB_Core::UploadDir()));
$upload_dir_len = strlen($upload_dir);

$all_files = str_replace('//','/',str_replace('\\', '/', list_files($upload_dir)));
$num_all_files = count($all_files);

$new_files = array();
$num_new_files = 0;
$num_files_to_add = 0;

// 1ps filter    (check extension, special file names, and filter existing file names and thumbnails)
$fext_blacklist = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', explode(',', WPFB_Core::GetOpt('fext_blacklist'))));
for($i = 0; $i < $num_all_files; $i++)
{
    $fn = $all_files[$i];
    $fbn = basename($fn);
    if(strlen($fn) < 2 || $fbn{0} == '.' || strpos($fn, '/.tmp') !== false
            || $fbn == '_wp-filebase.css' || strpos($fbn, '_caticon.') !== false
            || in_array($fn, $db_files)
            || !is_file($fn) || !is_readable($fn)
            || (!empty($fext_blacklist) && in_array(trim(strrchr($fbn, '.'),'.'), $fext_blacklist)) // check for blacklisted extension
        )
        continue;
    $new_files[$num_new_files] = $fn;
    $num_new_files++;
}

$num_files_to_add = $num_new_files;



$thumbnails = array();  
// look for thumnails
// find files that have names formatted like thumbnails e.g. file-XXxYY.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)
for($i = 1; $i < $num_new_files; $i++)
{
    $len = strrpos($new_files[$i], '.');

    // file and thumbnail should be neighbours in the list, so only check the prev element for matching name
    if(strlen($new_files[$i-1]) > ($len+2) && substr($new_files[$i-1],0,$len) == substr($new_files[$i],0,$len) && !in_array($new_files[$i-1], $db_files))
    {
        $suffix = substr($new_files[$i-1], $len);

        $matches = array();
        if(preg_match(WPFB_File::$thumbnail_regex, $suffix, $matches) && ($is = getimagesize($new_files[$i-1])))
        {
            if($is[0] == $matches[1] && $is[1] == $matches[2])
            {
                //ok, found a thumbnail here
                $thumbnails[$new_files[$i]] = basename($new_files[$i-1]);
                $new_files[$i-1] = ''; // remove the file from the list
                $num_files_to_add--;
                continue;
            }
        }           
    }
}


if(WPFB_Core::GetOpt('base_auto_thumb')) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_new_files; $i++)
    {
        $len = strrpos($new_files[$i], '.');
        $ext = strtolower(substr($new_files[$i], $len+1));

        if($ext != 'jpg' && $ext != 'png' && $ext != 'gif') {
            $prefix = substr($new_files[$i], 0, $len);

            for($ii = $i-1; $ii >= 0; $ii--)
            {
                if(substr($new_files[$ii],0, $len) != $prefix) break;                       
                $e = strtolower(substr($new_files[$ii], $len+1));
                if($e == 'jpg' || $e == 'png' || $e == 'gif') {
                    $thumbnails[$new_files[$i]] = basename($new_files[$ii]);
                    $new_files[$ii] = ''; // remove the file from the list
                    $num_files_to_add--;    
                    break;              
                }
            }

            for($ii = $i+1; $ii < $num_new_files; $ii++)
            {
                if(substr($new_files[$ii],0, $len) != $prefix) break;                       
                $e = strtolower(substr($new_files[$ii], $len+1));
                if($e == 'jpg' || $e == 'png' || $e == 'gif') {
                    $thumbnails[$new_files[$i]] = basename($new_files[$ii]);
                    $new_files[$ii] = ''; // remove the file from the list
                    $num_files_to_add--;
                    break;              
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if($output && $num_files_to_add > 0) {
    echo "<p>";
    printf(__('%d Files found, %d new.', WPFB), $num_all_files, $num_files_to_add);
    echo "</p>";

    include(WPFB_PLUGIN_ROOT.'extras/progressbar.class.php');
    $progress_bar = new progressbar(0, $num_files_to_add);
    $progress_bar->print_code();
} else {
    if($output) self::DEcho('done!</p>');
}

for($i = 0; $i < $num_new_files; $i++)
{
    $fn = $new_files[$i];
    if(empty($fn)) continue;
    $fbn = basename($fn);

    $res = WPFB_Admin::AddExistingFile($fn, empty($thumbnails[$fn]) ? null : $thumbnails[$fn]);         
    if(empty($res['error']))
        $result['added'][] = empty($res['file']) ? substr($fn, $upload_dir_len) : $res['file'];
    else
        $result['error'][] = $res['error'] . " (file $fn)";

    if(!empty($progress_bar))
        $progress_bar->step(1);
}

if(!empty($progress_bar))
    $progress_bar->complete();

// chmod
if($output) self::DEcho('<p>Setting permissions...');
@chmod ($upload_dir, octdec(WPFB_PERM_DIR));
for($i = 0; $i < count($db_files); $i++)
{
    if(file_exists($db_files[$i]))
    {
        @chmod ($db_files[$i], octdec(WPFB_PERM_FILE));
        if(!is_writable($db_files[$i]) && !is_writable(dirname($db_files[$i])))
            $result['warnings'][] = sprintf(__('File <b>%s</b> is not writable!', WPFB), substr($db_files[$i], $upload_dir_len));
    }
}
if($output) self::DEcho('done!</p>');

// sync categories
if($output) self::DEcho('<p>Syncing categories... ');
$result['updated_categories'] = self::SyncCats();
if($output) self::DEcho('done!</p>');

wpfb_call('Setup','ProtectUploadPath');
WPFB_File::UpdateTags();

return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the `md5_file()` function. Do the memory problems persist when hashing is disabled? For calculating md5 the file has to be read into memory. I'm not sure about the PHP implementation details but this could be the problem especially with big files.

If you need hashing take a look at the comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php - they suggest using the openssl `md5sum` utility instead of `md5_file()`. `md5sum` is started via `exec()` so php memory limits do not apply. It should be more battle-tested with large and huge files.

```
$result = explode("  ", exec("md5sum $file_path"));
echo "Hash = ".$result[0]."<br />";
```

So you try to replace:

```
if($hash_sync) $file_hash = @md5_file($file_path);
```

with:

```
if($hash_sync) {
  $file_hash = explode("  ", exec("md5sum $file_path"));
  $file_hash = $file_hash[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `emteh's` below answer to also amend another if statement within wp-filebase, should anyone want to fix their issues.

*Line 99, where it says*

```
if($hash_sync) {
  $file_hash = explode("  ", exec("md5sum $file_path"));
  $file_hash = $file_hash[0];
}
```

// new lines to fix line 115 if statement

```
$new_file_hash = explode("  ", exec("md5sum $file_path"));
$new_file_hash = $new_file_hash[0];
```

Line 115 or so replace

```
$file->file_hash = $hash_sync ? $file_hash : @md5_file($file_path);
```

with

```
$file->file_hash = $hash_sync ? $file_hash : $new_file_hash;
```